# Inherit href destination from <a> to <img> tag using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of `divs` that possess the same `className (.sampleClass)` of which contain both an `a` and `img` element. I have managed to inherit the `href` value from `a` to `img`, however, due to these elements residing inside `divs` with the same `className`, the `href` inheritance is applied to all `img` elements using only the first `href` value of `a` identified inside of a `div` with `.sampleClass`.

HTML before JavaScript:

```
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="example.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someImg.png" />
 <p>text</p>
 <a><span>text</span></a>
</div>

<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="random.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someOtherImg.png" />
 <p>text</p>
 <a><span>text</span></a>
</div>
```

The following JavaScript (vanilla) was used:

```
var aHref = document.querySelector(".sampleClass > a").getAttribute("href");
var img = document.querySelectorAll("img"); /* or (".sampleClass > img") */

img.forEach(function(inheritHrefImg) {
  inheritHrefImg.setAttribute("href", aHref);
})
```

HTML after JavaScript:

```
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="example.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someImg.png" href="example.html" /> /* this is correct */ 
 <p>text</p>
 <a><span>text</span></a>
</div>

<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="random.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someOtherImg.png" href="example.html" /> /* want href to be "random.html" */
 <p>text</p>
 <a><span>text</span></a>
</div>
```

I need a way to indicate `img` elements to only target the `href` of the `a` element within the `div` of which both that `img` and `a` resides.

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: Unfortunately giving an individual `className` to each `div`, although a solution, is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how a href attribute on an `img` tag will help.. But one way you can do this is by querying for the parent divs and operating on it's children in a for loop.

Note: If you are using that `href` attribute on the `img` tag programmatically through JS, it may be better to make it a `data-*` attribute..

Sample:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.sampleClass');
divs.forEach(function(div) {
  var aTag = div.querySelector('a');
  var iTag = div.querySelector('img');
  if (!aTag || !iTag) {
    // This div does not have an image or anchor tag, skip
    return;
  }
  iTag.setAttribute('href', aTag.href);
});
```

```html
<div class="sampleClass">
  <h2><a href="example.html">text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/someImg.png" />
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
  <h2><a href="random.html">text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/someOtherImg.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the `div`s instead. Also note that your example is missing the first `</div>` end tag, I presume:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sampleClass')
  .forEach(sampleClass => {
    sampleClass.children[1].setAttribute('href', sampleClass.children[0].children[0].getAttribute('href'));
  });
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="example.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someImg.png" />
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="random.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someOtherImg.png" />
</div>
```

But `img`s should not have `href`s, I don't know what that's supposed to do; it would be much more elegant to simply enclose them in another dynamically created `a`, like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sampleClass')
  .forEach(sampleClass => {
    const { href } = sampleClass.children[0].children[0];
    const img = sampleClass.children[1];
    img.remove();
    const newA = document.createElement('a');
    newA.href = href;
    newA.appendChild(img);
    const newAinsert = sampleClass.insertBefore(newA, sampleClass.children[1]);
  });
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="example.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someImg.png" />
 <p>text</p>
 <span>text</span>
</div>
<div class="sampleClass">
 <h2><a href="random.html">text</a></h2>
 <img src="./img/someOtherImg.png" />
 <p>text</p>
 <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method, I tried it however the <img> is sent to the last position; my fault, as I did not mention there were more elements after <img> that were previously unnecessary. I have edited them into my question.